# Why am I getting autoconf AC_* macro errors?

Tags: configuration, compiling, translation

I am trying to build this language modelling toolkit but I run into this problem when trying to get it set up. I am trying to understand what the error means, and what I should do to fix it, I dont understand because I had just installed the auto tools but now I am getting this problem and it seems to be one of them.

```
USER@WH:~/irstlm-5.70.04$ ./regenerate-makefiles.sh 
Calling  
Calling /usr/bin/aclocal...
Calling /usr/bin/autoconf...
configure.in:18: error: possibly undefined macro: AC_DISABLE_SHARED
  If this token and others are legitimate, please use m4_pattern_allow.
  See the Autoconf documentation.
configure.in:19: error: possibly undefined macro: AC_PROG_LIBTOOL
autoconf failed
```

Comment: Found the problem, apparently my files weren’t in the right directory causing this problem to occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, apparently my files weren’t in the right directory causing this problem to occur.

Comment: Not much of an answer,  Can you expand a little which files were in the wrong directory and which directory should they have been in?